# How to implement WS-Federation using Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2 with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, thinktecture-ident-server, ws-federation

I'm just hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

We have Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2 running and working beutifully with out ASP.Net apps.
I'm now working on an app with node.js. No Microsoft code at all.

Can someone give me some links to get me started? Is there any tutorials out there that I haven't been able to find?

I found https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-wsfed but i'm not sure if it does what I need. (or more to the point how to get it to do what I need)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I have found the solution to this in case anyone else ends up here

Just need to use http://passportjs.org/ and use the [passport-wsfed-saml2](https://github.com/auth0/passport-wsfed-saml2) stategy

Comment: Yeah i did. Although I ended up creating an ASP.Net MVC app in the end and used AngularJs for the client side code. Just works better with less hassle for wsfed. My current project is APS.Net Web API 2 with the MVC controller (home/index) simply redirecting to a ReactJs SPA that calls the API endpoints. Works for our environment of mostly .net stuff on iis and let's me use NPM for the reactjs SPA while still using wsfed the "microsoft way"